# How to capture dynamic url using jmeter?

Tags: json, dynamic, jmeter

How can I capture the value of "LOGMEIN" from below response and pass it on to next request?

```html
 <script id='modelJson' type='application/json'>
                    {&quot;loginUrl&quot;:&quot;/login?LOGMEIN=3a70c35a225de4091549768c09aafe68&quot;,&quot;antiForgery&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;idsrv.xsrf&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;zGaQjcvchQVfbGaDtXEsXjRlHu6vfum91AZkaV3MFi_hMdiR9FQ7372rNnTgpxGTmInSXvRhP0NDg2ZEVIZllyWLJ6bKinQLbLvzyj826HQ&quot;},&quot;allowRememberMe&quot;:true,&quot;rememberMe&quot;:false,&quot;username&quot;:null,&quot;externalProviders&quot;:[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Microsoft&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Microsoft&quot;,&quot;href&quot;:&quot;https://xyx.abc.net/external?provider=Microsoft&amp;signin=3a70c35a225de4091549768c09aafe68&quot;}],&quot;additionalLinks&quot;:null,&quot;clientName&quot;:&quot;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) with Template `$1$` and Match No.1 with expression:

```
LOGMEIN=([^ &]*)&
```

> Allows the user to extract values from a server response using a Perl-type regular expression. As a post-processor, this element will execute after each Sample request in its scope, applying the regular expression, extracting the requested values, generate the template string, and store the result into the given variable name.

Comment: I tried this but its not working. Is there any other option to do it?